# Keeping a string of text together on one line

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to keep a string of text on one line, so that if the div width gets to small, the whole string will drop to the next line instead of half of it?

Example:

```
"Industry Updates - 8th
 September 2013"
```

often this happens on mobile browers whereas with to smaller width, the ideal situation is that the whole date stays together giving:

```
"Industry Updates - 
 8th September 2013"
```

So is there a tag to use or a css trick to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You want to use a non-breaking space in your HTML markup `&nbsp;` instead of a normal space.

#### HTML

```
"Industry Updates - 8th&nbsp;September&nbsp;2013"
```

Answer (score 87):

CSS

```
.nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

HTML

```
<span class="nowrap">Industry Updates -</span>
<span class="nowrap">8th September 2013</span>
```

Any element with `white-space: nowrap` stays on one line

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. All done through css, without any need to modify the original string.

Comment: Actually, in this example, you ARE modifying the original string as the string has to be broken and wrapped in tags. One issue however in using the accepted &nbsp; solution is that it will not validate in XHTML5, though it should validate in text/html HTML5. You can work around this by using the appropriate encoding (utf8) and &#160; in place of the &nbsp; html entity or you can use the hex variant of the entity &#xa0;.