# How to ensure two words stay on the same line?

Tags: html, css, highlight

I am making a person website for myself. In my short bio, I have a few words (or groups of words) that are highlighted. In some of my testing, I have noticed that sometimes two words get split, so the highlighting effect looks like crap.

Here's a picture of what it should look like, and what it looks like if the font changes, respectively:

[image: Should Look Like]

[image: Don't want this happening]

Notice how "web developer" get's pushed apart to two lines. Is there any way I can ensure they stay together?

Comment: `web&nbsp;developer`

Comment: `white-space:nowrap;`

Comment: Duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753828/keeping-a-string-of-text-together-on-one-line

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Just apply a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) between the two words:

```
word1&nbsp;word2
```

This is especially useful when it comes to french punctuation and numbers

If you need this on a larger scale then you can use CSS:

```css
div {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>word 1 word2 word3</div>
```

You would have to use this method if you are trying to make sure text and a **svg** stay together on the same line, non-breaking space does not work for that.

You can create a nowrap class so you can apply it anywhere:

```
<span class="nowrap">No one can wrap us</span>
```

Answer (score 5):

The CSS way:

```
a { white-space: nowrap; }
```