# Force two words to be always together in a line

Tags: javascript, css, line-breaks

I have this line:

```
Welcome to the nicest home
```

This line is inside a flex div width responsive width.
When with is small enough, this happens

```
Welcome to the
nicest home
```

Is there a way with which I can force `home` and  to be always together? So in the example I would get

```
Welcome to the
nicest
home
```

Comment: A [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)?

Comment: Set it not to wrap with: 'white-space:nowrap;' [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ya0zkfrm/)

Comment: @akaBase I had the same thought, but that will prevent *all* line breaks, not just those between the last words/icons/emojis

Comment: Could you not set them in a span and set the nowrap to the span?

Comment: this library might be useful: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/emoji-regex it only targets emojis though, you could replace each emoji with something like `<span class="nowrap">emoji</span>`

Comment: One related question to search for might be for a similar problem in the Czech language, which forbids wrapping after the words "k", "s", "v" and "z"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ensure two words stay on the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410166/how-to-ensure-two-words-stay-on-the-same-line)

Comment: @donalduck yes it does, t.j.crowder you're right, thanks, akaBase you're right too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method to achieve this would be to replace the last whitespace found in the string with a non-breaking space entity, `&nbsp;`.

You can use JS to do this to all elements you decorate with a given class:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.no-orphans').forEach(el => {
  el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/ (?=[^ ]*$)/i, "&nbsp;");
});
```

```css
p { width: 100px; }
```

```html
<p>Original:<br />Welcome to the nicest home </p>

<p class="no-orphans">Corrected:<br />Welcome to the nicest home </p>
```

The only caveat here is that the end of the content within the `.no-orphans` element cannot be a HTML element, only a text node

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, a non-breaking space will do the trick.

To include it in the HTML, we usually use the symbol code: `&nbsp;`

(Drag the corner of the box to resize and test the example)

```css
div {
  display: block;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div>Welcome to the nicest home&nbsp;</div>
```